# require_once(); Does not respond

Tags: php, foreach, constants, require-once

I want to include files from a folder and although it does work in "LIB_PATH",
php cannot find any files in P_C_PATH which is the sub folder inside LIB_PATH.

Any ideas?

```
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT', DS . 'home' . DS. 'servername' . DS . 'public_html'.DS.'site');
defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');
defined('P_C_PATH') ? null : define('P_C_PATH', LIB_PATH.DS.'project_classes');

foreach (glob(LIB_PATH.DS.'*.php') as $filename)
{
    require_once($filename);
}

foreach (glob(P_C_PATH.DS.'*.php') as $classname)
{
    require_once($classname);
}
```

Comment: If you really feel like saving space, you could just use `defined('...') or define('...', '...')` instead of the ternary operator.

Comment: This does not work for me in this current project. Tnks though.

Comment: For class names you might want to implement an auto loader.

Comment: First, add some `echo $filename;` and show us what are the generated paths

Comment: Tnks  GolezTrol i'll try that.

Comment: Tnks  GolezTrol you where right! __autoload works fine!